# Preserve data after movement of pragment

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, fragment

Click the button to move the other text, then receive the data and return it. The problem is that the data except textview disappears from the page in the first instance. How can I keep the data that I've received from the Recycleview?

Comment: if you put a reproducer to github it will be easier to solve. or put some code to show the case here.